# Can I use @Import in Spring JUnit tests?

Tags: java, spring, config

I have mutual exclusive config configuration classes in my project: `Config1` and `Config2`, I want to select one in the unit test, like:

```
public class Config1 {
    @Bean
    FooBean foo() {
        return new FooBean();
    }
}

(I must remove the `@Configuration` annotation, so I can choose one in the application)
```

And,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Import(Config1.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Inject
    FooBean foo;
    // ...
 }
```

However, it seems like `JUnit4ClassRunner` doesn't see the `@Import` annotation on the test class.

Answer (score 1):

From the Documentation of @Import:

> Provides functionality equivalent to
>   the {@literal <import/>} element in
>   Spring XML.Only supported for actual
>   {@literal @Configuration}-annotated
>   classes.

So you are right, the annotation is ignored.